# Use InstallShield license for multi machines

Tags: windows, jenkins, installshield

I have a Windows machine, **hold a license for InstallShield.**

I configure my Jenkins slave to use the InstallShield as a global tool.

With a **Jenkins slave** (Windows machine) I build .Net code.

When i use this InstallShield tool on the slave

> "Path\to\InstallShield\server\IsCmdBld.exe" -x  -w  -p  Path\to\ism\xxxxx.ism

it throws this exception:

> ISDEV : fatal error -7159: The product license has expired or has not yet been initialized.

There is a way to use this global tool without passing the InstallShield license to the Jenkins slave machine?

Comment: You probably have a support agreement? This sounds like a definite support issue you can resolve quickly on the phone with Installshield? I see plenty of these error messages mentioned in their community forum: https://community.flexerasoftware.com. Maybe launch the GUI (isdev.exe) and see if it asks you to activate, and if that works?